# Add DOM element when transcluding except for the last one child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I would like to add a `<hr>` element between each clone of my transclude function except for the last one clone.

The parent directive have a custom HTML template.
In this template, I call a Attribute directive to transclude the elements.

**Sample:**

```
function directiveTransclude() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(function (clone, scope) {
                element.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

This directive help me to manually handle the transclude.
I just have to figure out now how to conditionnally add the `<hr>`.
I assume to do that I need to add for example `element.append('<hr>');` after the first append.

So how could I know how many elements the transclude have to append ?
Is there a $last value or something to tell me that this is the last loop ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just in case you wonder:**

It's late but I just find the solution by using an alternative (with CSS).

As mentioned by @Aaron Pool, I can use `last-child` selector to achieve that.

> the `last-of-type` selector is finicky, and the `last-child` selector is actually applied to the child

It's better (faster than DOM injection and safer visually speaking, because `<hr>` could easily get edited by CSS rules).

I already tried that nevertheless it didn't works as expected.
Despite, today I figure out that my LESS code was that:

```
&:last-child
```

Instead of

```
:last-child
```

So I was focusing the wrong DOM element, sadly.
I'm happy even if now I feel so dumb.
Greetings and happy new year !

Answer (score 0):

The controller has been instantiated by the time the link function runs, so I would just keep track of it in a controller attribute.

I'm assuming in the below example that you're passing this directive a collection to iterate over, or at least a count of number of elements you want. I'll also assume that argument is named `collection`, and that you're using `bindToController` so that this directive binding is accessible on the controller by this point. Finally, I'm assuming you've also attached an attribute to your controller named `iterationCount`.

```
function directiveTransclude() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            ctrl.iterationCount++;
            transclude(function (clone, scope) {
                element.append(clone);
                if(ctrl.iterationCount < (ctrl.collection.length - 1)) {
                  element.append('hr');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Although, my suggestion would be to do this with css, if `<hr>` isn't some sort of strange requirement. Using a border and the `last-child` selector would be MUCH simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow. By the way, I tried the CSS way by calling sibling selectors like :last-child on the parent or directly :last-of-type on the child nevertheless that way is not working (children are directives with their own template, so multiple DOM levels here).

Comment: the `last-of-type` selector is finicky, and the `last-child` selector is actually applied to the child. It means "If I am the last-child". I was also confused by this for quite some time.